# How to emulate a MoveJ, or MoveL movement using ROS?

Tags: ros-melodic, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-control, arm-controller, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently using a UR5 in simulation and would like to know if there is a way to emulate the way that the UR5 moves from one joint target to another joint target. The movement/trajectory I want to emulate is the same as the one that is  provided by a *MoveJ* command. Basically, I believe it is simply a linear interpolation from one joint target to another for each joint with parabolic blends at the beginning and at the end of the motion (for smooth acceleration/deceleration). I don't need collision detection.

I could use *roscontrol* and simply send the joint target, but I believe it isn't going to result in the same motion/trajectory as a *MoveJ* command would. I believe its only some type of PID controller that increases the output based on the distance to target, which is not what I want.

It tried using the planner from *MoveIt*, but it results in a crazy trajectory that's generated between the initial robot configuration to the end configuration, sometimes spinning three times around its base. I also find *MoveIt* extremely tedious to use and not intuitive, but that might just be because I haven't use it enough yet. So far I am not a fan of it.

Does somebody know a simple way to achieve what I am trying to do? Are there any existing packages that I could leverage to do this task?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351835/how-to-emulate-a-movej,-or-movel-movement-using-ros-?/) by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-08**:
Observation: "the ROS stack" is a bit meaningless. You mention a few packages, but they are not really part of any particular stack.

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-08**:
Removed the term stack. I don't mind changing the title of the question if you have a recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I could use roscontrol and simply send the joint target, but I believe it isn't going to result in the same motion/trajectory as a MoveJ command would. I believe its only some type of PID controller that increases the output based on the distance to target, which is not what I want.

`ros_control` contains many controllers, you seem to describe (one variant of) the `position_controller`s?

For trajectory based control, even if the trajectory contains only two points (ie: departure and destination), you could use the [joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller).

> It tried using the planner from MoveIt, but it results in a crazy trajectory

that's typically caused by misconfiguration (ie: too few constraints). Without proper constraints, *any* trajectory is a valid one, as long as it doesn't collide with anything, so there is no difference between "spinning three times around its base" and "a simple linear interpolation".

> The movement/trajectory I want to emulate is the same as the one that is provided by a MoveJ command

Well it 's going to be using MoveIt again, but if you can stomach that you could perhaps take a look at [wiki/pilz_industrial_motion](http://wiki.ros.org/pilz_industrial_motion).

---

If you'd be using real hardware (or `ursim`), I'd almost suggest you could just as well write a simple Python script sending URScript statements to `tcp://:30002`. Could you perhaps give some more information on what sort of functionality you are looking to achieve which made you start / work with ROS?

Also, with real hardware, and when using `ur_robot_driver`, you'd need to use the [ScaledJointTrajectoryController](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/tree/b4665181fb7e3b2360750a88bf01a8b8bfa83a04/ur_controllers) or you'd lose many of the advantages which `ur_robot_driver` offers.

If all of this is still too tedious, I would probably recommend using something like [SintefManufacturing/python-urx](https://github.com/SintefManufacturing/python-urx) or a similar library, but that does not come with any ROS integration (or at least: I don't know of any).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-08**:
Thanks for the answer. The project I am currently working on does the following: generate 6D pose, calculate IK, repeat. Then, I want to see if I can move from one joint target to another without collision using a simple MoveJ.

I believe the best solution is the one you've proposed, which is to use ursim. https://www.universal-robots.com/download/ I was wondering if there were any easier way, but it seems that this is the easiest approach AFAIK.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-08**:
`ursim` would not tell you whether you are in collision. It does not do anything but simulate the robot itself (or actually: the controller).

I'm not sure it would be the easiest / best approach.

Unless you're only really interested in self-collisions of course.

---

Edit: using MoveIt may actually be the faster approach here. A combination of something like [RobotState::setFromIK(..)](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/robot_model_and_robot_state/robot_model_and_robot_state_tutorial.html) and linear interpolating (perhaps even using `computeCartesianPath(..)`) and then checking for self-collision using the [PlanningScene](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene/planning_scene_tutorial.html) could work.

There's no need to actually execute any of the motions you describe IIUC. So using `ursim` sounds like it would waste a lot of time.

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-11**:
I've looked deeper into the ursim software, and if I could add tools and objects within the virtual scene, than it would have been exactly what I am looking for. I am simply interested in knowing how the robot moves from one joint configuration to another, using a moveJ command, and visually assess if its going to self-collide (with its tool added to the end-effector) or collide with objects within the workspace of the robot. Then, I need to execute this on the real UR robot using a MoveJ command.

> and linear interpolating (perhaps even using computeCartesianPath(..)

I don't think this would work because the linear interpolation has to be in joint space IIUC.

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-11**:
By going through all your recommendations again, I think that using the joint_trajectory_controller is what I am looking for. I need to understand how to use it now. Would you have any links to share that I can look at that explains how to use it (e.g. tutorials, examples, etc)?

edit:
So far I've found those resources to be very useful, presented in order of usefulness:
I'll add more if I find more useful info.

[The construct tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K09E-_2M-vQ)

[Tiago robot tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TIAGo/Tutorials/trajectory_controller)

[PR2 tutorial](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/pr2_controllers(2f)Tutorials(2f)Moving(20)the(20)arm(20)using(20)the(20)Joint(20)Trajectory(20)Action.html)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-13**:
You should open a new question for this, but I think the [MoveIt tutorials](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/) and the [concepts page](https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/concepts/) will help.

I'll repeat the recommendation for https://github.com/PilzDE/pilz_industrial_motion , which generates trajectories like MoveL and MoveJ would.

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-14**:
I've finished implementing the solution using joint_trajectory_controller. It was a little bit easier than I thought. Thanks for the recommendation.